# pam_mount often unable to mount and hangs for minutes

Tags: mount, 16.04, samba, cifs

I have some centrally managed Ubuntu workstations that authenticate users against Active Directory and mount user home folders on logon with pam_mount. This usually works as expected, but **sometimes the home folders will not mount and for every volume to mount I get this in** `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
(mount.c:72): Messages from underlying mount program:
(mount.c:76): mount error(115): Operation now in progress
(mount.c:76): Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
(pam_mount.c:522): mount of data/users/username/documents failed
```

It hangs for over 10 seconds on each volume, so logging in or doing `su` for instance can literally take minutes. When I open another terminal during this, I exceptionally get

```
I have no name!@VP-OH-01L:~$
```

I see this in `syslog`:

```
Jun 11 18:28:16 VP-OH-01L kernel: [35851.544770] Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
Jun 11 18:28:16 VP-OH-01L kernel: [35851.544787] cifs_vfs_err: 10 callbacks suppressed
Jun 11 18:28:16 VP-OH-01L kernel: [35851.544789] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
Jun 11 18:28:16 VP-OH-01L kernel: [35851.544912] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13
Jun 11 18:28:26 VP-OH-01L kernel: [35861.554651] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
Jun 11 18:28:26 VP-OH-01L kernel: [35861.554822] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -115
Jun 11 18:28:36 VP-OH-01L kernel: [35871.564834] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
Jun 11 18:28:36 VP-OH-01L kernel: [35871.565010] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -115
```

It still logs in (and does not warn about offline login that it does when there is no connection) so there is a connection between the workstation and the domain.

I'm going to dump all my related configs below; sorry about a wall of text! In `/etc/security/pam_mount.conf.xml` I have about 10 of configs like this:

```
<volume user="*" fstype="cifs" server="ou.domain.com" path="data/users/%(USER)/documents" mountpoint="~/Documents" options="uid=%(USER),gid=100,dir_mode=0700,file_mode=0700,nounix,iocharset=utf8,rw,sec=ntlmsspi" />
```

In `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_winbind.so krb5_auth krb5_ccache_type=FILE cached_login try_first_pass
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so
auth    optional            pam_mount.so disable_interactive
```

In `/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
session [default=1]         pam_permit.so
session requisite           pam_deny.so
session required            pam_permit.so
session optional            pam_umask.so
session required            pam_unix.so 
session optional            pam_winbind.so 
session optional            pam_mount.so disable_interactive
session optional            pam_systemd.so
```

In `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   COMPUTER_FQDN   COMPUTER_HOSTNAME
```

In `/etc/krb5.conf`:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = OU.DOMAIN.COM
ticket_lifetime = 24000
default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac des-cbc-md5
default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac des-cbc-md5
permitted_enctypes = rc4-hmac des-cbc-md5
dns_lookup_realm = true
dns_lookup_kdc = true
dns_fallback = yes
krb4_config = /etc/krb.conf
krb4_realms = /etc/krb.realms
kdc_timesync = 1
ccache_type = 4
forwardable = true
proxiable = true

[realms]
OU.DOMAIN.COM = {
    kdc = ou.domain.com:88
    default_domain = ou.domain.com
}

[domain_realm]
.ou.domain.com = OU.DOMAIN.COM
ou.domain.com = OU.DOMAIN.COM

[login]
krb4_convert = true
krb4_get_tickets = false
```

In `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:         compat winbind
group:          compat winbind
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files
hosts:          files dns wins
networks:       files
protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files
netgroup:   nis
```

In `/etc/security/pam_winbind.conf`:

```
cached_login = yes
```

And finally, in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

```
[global]
netbios name                    = COMPUTER_HOSTNAME
security                        = ADS
workgroup                       = OU
realm                           = OU.DOMAIN.COM
encrypt passwords               = yes
idmap config *:backend          = rid
idmap config *:range            = 5000-100000
dedicated keytab file           = /etc/krb5.keytab
kerberos method                 = secrets and keytab
winbind refresh tickets         = yes
winbind trusted domains only    = no
winbind use default domain      = yes
winbind enum users              = yes
winbind enum groups             = yes
winbind offline logon           = yes
client ntlmv2 auth              = yes
client ldap sasl wrapping       = sign
template shell                  = /bin/bash
wins server                     = 192.168.0.70
name resolve order              = lmhosts host wins bcast
```

The workstations have Ubuntu 16.04. This happens very randomly when I start up the computer and login (or later `su` to another domain user) and I haven't found a way to reproduce it. Sometimes it works like a charm. The workstations are connected to LAN via Ethernet and the DC is in the same LAN (good connection). I'm out of ideas and any help or suggestions will be much appreciated :)

Comment: I am seeing the same problems on my side. Pretty similar setup too...

Comment: Is this topic still relevant? I'm wondering about the "I have no name!@VP-OH-01L:~$". If the username is not available in the login-environment, then the mount of the folders cannot work. I would suggest launching SSSD with a higher debug level and check if there are any warnings/errors.

Comment: I never found out the reason, but I haven't seen this problem lately. I guess some update eventually fixed it.